# Can't resolve all parameters for NavbarComponent after injecting a service

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster, angular6, angular-services

I'm using angular 6 and I've an issue in a component `NavBarComponent`.

issue : `Can't resolve all parameters for NavbarComponent: (?, [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object]).`

Here is the code of `NavbarComponent`:

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    constructor(
        private loginService: LoginService,
        private languageService: JhiLanguageService,
        private languageHelper: JhiLanguageHelper,
        private principal: Principal,
        private loginModalService: LoginModalService,
        private profileService: ProfileService,
        private router: Router
    ) {
    }
```

The issue comes from LoginService I guess (because of the `(?)`.)
So here is the code of `LoginService`:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class LoginService {
    constructor(
        private extraUsrService: ExtraUserService,
        private currentExtraUsrService: CurrentExtraUserService,
        private languageService: JhiLanguageService,
        private principal: Principal,
        private trackerService: JhiTrackerService,
        private authServerProvider: AuthServerProvider        
    ) {}
```

I know that if I remove the `ExtraUserService` line I haven't the error. But if I keep it. 
here's `ExtraUserService`:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ExtraUserService {
    private resourceUrl = SERVER_API_URL + 'api/extra-users';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
```

For each service, it's a singleton because of `providedIn: root`. 
I guess it's a circular import problem, but I have difficulties to find it. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Is `HttpClient` in `ExtraUserService` resolvable? Try removing it and see if it works?

Comment: Hello @TalhaJunaid finally I simlified the problem because I just notices that if I want directly to use ExtraUserService inside LoginService it does the same issue. I neet to keep http in ExtraUserService because I use it in the class